# Check class existence after clicking an element

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm trying to brush up my javascript and have a simple setup of html, CSS and JS connected.

The *console.log* prints out `Clicked` so I know it's working, but my code is wrong and I can't see it. The element is not checking for the existing class 'red'.

I'd like to check if the class `red` is there, and if it is then remove it and if its not, then add the class.

Can any of you point me in a direction?

TIA

```js
tekst.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Clicked");
  tekst.classList.add("red");

  if (tekst.classList.contains("")) {
    tekst.classList.add("red");
  } else if (tekst.classList.contains("red")) {
    tekst.classList.remove("red");
  }
});
```

Comment: You add the class and then you're checking if it exists on the element. Of course it does exist when you add it every time before checking...

Answer (score 3):

Your code works. But you're adding red and then immediately removing it so you won't see a change.

The alternative to the conditional is to just [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) the class instead. (I've added a timeout so you can see this working).

```js
const tekst = document.querySelector('.tekst');

// Comment this line out to see the reverse effect
tekst.classList.add("red");
setTimeout(() => tekst.classList.toggle('red'), 2000);
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="tekst">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, you just need to use toggle method like so:

```js
  tekst.classList.toggle("red");
```